# Camera not opening on some Android phones within CapacitorJS application

Tags: android, html, webview, camera, capacitor

I have a CapacitorJS application which I use standard HTML to open the native camera

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>`

On almost every phone I have tried it works fine. But on a couple phones, one specific model Motorola Moto G31 and the Pixel 5 emulator, instead of opening the camera it goes to the file browser.

I created a test page outside the app with all various combinations of the input tag. All of the ones that I expected to work did work within the native browser.

After copying these test tags into the CapacitorJS app none worked with all sending me to the file browser.

The variations I have tried include

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" />
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" capture="camera" />
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" capture />
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" capture="user" />
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Some seemed totally wrong but other stackoverflow posts seemed to suggest some should work.

The manifest has permissions of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

One post recommended placing the permissions at the top before the <application tag which also didn't help.

I note there are two errors in the console

> D/Capacitor: Unable to find a Capacitor plugin to handle permission requestCode, trying Cordova plugins 190163686

> W/Capacitor/FileChooser: Media capture intent could not be launched. Falling back to default file picker.

Has anyone seen anything like this or have any suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.
This needed to be added to the Android Manifest. It is interesting why some phones were happy to allow this to work even when they were running Android 11.

```
<queries>
    <!-- Camera -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>

    <!-- Gallery -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Which version of the <input> tag did you finally end up with? Which one is working for you?

Comment: You are a lifesaver. This works!